# How to access User-Agent in Python to get my browser details , every method i try returns Python-usrlib 2.7

Tags: python, user-agent

i want to access browser name and version in python by sending out a request.is this the ideal method or is there any other way? because all the methods which provide user agents give PythonUserlib2.7 as user agent,i want my actual user agent.

Comment: What does this mean? How would you identify a user's browser by *sending* a request? And where is your code?

Comment: im writing a python script in such a way that when it is executed in a client computer it will give the browser details.how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're familiar with HTTP requests and their structure, if not, [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)'s a link to the RFC documentation for HTTP/1.1 requests, at the bottom of the page, there is a list of links to header fields.

The user-agent is a field in the HTTP request header that identifies the `entity` that sends the request, by `entity` I mean the program you used to send the request, that's hosted on your machine. Things like the browser type, version and operating system, are sent in the user-agent field.

So, when you use urllib.request to send a request, urllib fills the HTTP request headers with the values *you* provide to it, otherwise, default values are used. That's why you get `PythonUserLib2.7` as a user-agent.

If you need the user-agent of a specific browser, you need to send request *using that browser*, you can do that in python by using a browser automation tool, like `selenium webdriver`. Which you can use to launch an instance of your browser, and go to websites.

I've worked only with `selenium webdriver`, and it doesn't have the capability to inspect sent/received packets/requests, in other words, you can't get HTTP requests/responses directly from `selenium`. 
As a work around, you can use `selenium`(or any other automation tool) to launch your browser, then go to a website that will give you your user-agent, and may even parse it.

Here's a link to [selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html), it explains how to get started with selenium and how to download the required packages.

If you search on google for `user-agent online`, *Google will tell you* what's your user agent.

Comment: but using selenium i need to specify the browser, i want my python script to be run on a different system and when he runs it it has to specify his browser details,i dont know what browser he is using so i cannot specify it in selenium.

Comment: That's right, as a work around, you can ask the user to provide the path to his browser (or browse to his browser executable), and add a couple of functions to your script that handle the path, and specify the browser to use with selenium.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? any code for handling the path?